# Set-theoretic equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A⊂U^{*},B⊂U.$ Find the set $X⊂U,$ that satisfies the equation.
>   $$(\overline{X \cup A}) \cup (X \cup \overline{A}) =B.$$

---

My thoughts:

$$\begin{align}B&=(\overline{X \cup A}) \cup (X \cup \overline{A})\\ & =  \overline{A} \cap \overline{X} \cup \overline{A} \cup X \\ &= \overline{A} \cup X.\end{align}$$
The last condition implies that  $\overline{A} \subset B$, and than $A∪B=U.$ Otherwise, the equation has no solution. If the last condition is satisfied, then suitable any set $X$, concluded between $A∩B$ и $B$. So, I came to the
necessity and sufficiency condition $$A∩B \subset X \subset B.$$

Autor's answer is $X = \overline{B}$. I think it's mistake. Can anyone explain that?

---

*$U$ — universal set.

Comment: The overlining is for the complementary set?

Comment: Just checking, does the over bar indicate set complement?

Comment: leo, GrahamKemp, Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your post you only proved that $B = \overline A \cup X \implies A\cap B \subseteq X \subseteq B$, although you're missing the parenthesis in the expression $(\overline A \cap \overline X)\cup \overline A \cup X$.

After parenthesizing it, your equality still holds:

\begin{align} (\overline A \cap \overline X)\cup \overline A \cup X &= [\overbrace{(\overline A\cup \overline A)}^{\overline A}\cap \overbrace{(\overline X \cup \overline A)}^{\;\;\supseteq \ \overline A}]\cup X \\ 
&= \overline A \cup X
\end{align}

Now, you know that $B = \overline A \cup X$. You can derive the inclusions from this:

$$  B = \overline A \cup X \implies X \subseteq B \text{ and } \overline A \subseteq B $$
\begin{align}
B = \overline A \cup X \implies A \cap B &= A \cap (\overline A  \cup X ) \\ 
&= \underbrace{(A \cap \overline A)}_{\varnothing} \cup (A \cap X) \\
&= A \cap X
\end{align}
$$ A \cap B = A \cap X \subseteq X \implies A \cap B \subseteq X$$

Hence, $B = X \cup \overline A \implies A \cap B \subseteq X \subseteq B$.

---

The converse only holds if you assume first that $\overline A \subseteq B$:

Let $U=\{1,2,3,4,5\}, A = \{1,2\}, B = \{2,3,4\}$.

Then $A \cap B = \{2\}$, so we can take $X = \{2,4\}$.

This $X$ fulfills the requirement that $A \cap B \subseteq X \subseteq B$, but $B \neq \overline A \cup X = \{3,4,5\} \cup \{2,4\}=\{2,3,4,5\}$, because $5 \notin B$.

---

Now, with that assumption, let's prove the converse: If $\overline A \subseteq B$ and $X$ is a set such that $A \cap B \subseteq X \subseteq B$, then $B = X \cup \overline A$

$(\subseteq)$: Let $b \in B$.

If $b \notin A$, then $b \in \overline A$, so $b \in X \cup \overline A$.
If $b \in A$, then, since $b \in B$ too,  $b \in B \cap A \subseteq X \cup \overline A$

$(\supseteq)$: Suppose $c \in X \cup \overline A$.

If $c \in \overline A$, then $c \in B$, because $\overline A \subseteq B$ by assumption.
If $c \notin \overline A$, then $c \in X$, because $c$ is in the union, and since $X \subseteq B$ we have $c \in B$.

Comment: Very nice proof! Well done! So, what is $X$? I see answer from here $\overline{B}$... But from our condition $A \cap B \subseteq X \subseteq B$ and $B = X \cup \overline A$  it's not obvious.

Comment: Thanks :). As you wrote in your post, $X$ can be any set containing $A \cap B$ and contained in $B$, given $\overline A \subseteq B$. One of the sets that works is actually $A \cap B$: $ (A \cap B) \cup \overline A = (A \cup \overline A) \cap (B \cup \overline A) = (U) \cap (B \cup \overline A) = B$, because $\overline A \subseteq B$. I don't think $\overline B$ works. Why do you think it does?

Comment: hm... Yes, you are right. But the answer still $\overline{B}$ :). I think it's autor's mistake.

Comment: @coldhunter, By the way, your сounterexample is wrong, bcz we need $A \cup B = U$.

Comment: The counter example is there to show that you need $\overline A \subseteq B$, which is equivalent to $A\cup B=U$. Why is the answer $\overline B$? It doesn't contain $A\cap B$ (unless it's empty) and it is only  a subset of $ B$ when it is empty...

Comment: @PersonaNonGrata you could post an answer explaining your answer :)

Comment: @coldhunter I don't understand... Fact that  $\overline{A} ⊆ B$  is $A∪B = U$ right, but your example is not fulfilled: number 5 belongs to the complement $A$, but not $B$. Or I mistaken? :)

Comment: The counterexample shows that $A \cap B \subseteq X \subseteq B$ does not imply $B=\overline A \cup X$. It shows that for the implication to hold you also need to assume that $\overline A \subseteq B$.